# Change background color of select characters of an input textfield

Tags: css, regex, background-color, html

The user enters a string into a traditional html input field (type="text").  For example, lets say the input is "2013/13/29".  At validation, the RegEx determin that 13 is invalid.  I want the "13"'s background-color to become red and all other character's background-color to become green.  Can this be done in HTML?  Perhaps the use of a span inside an input tag.

Comment: Did you see it anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, you can't add a span inside input tag.
try using jqueryUI datetimepicker, it will save you a lot of time. 
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I am currently using a datetime picker from jQueryUI.  However i also indented to use this concept for coordinate input aswell.I was looking for a visual way to identify what characters are incorrect/invalid.  I.e., changing their background-color, font-color, etc.  Could i achieve this using another type of widget.

Comment: You could also use jquery for simply field validations, together with changing their styles.